# How to use actionButton to control the values of projects in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

everyone. I want to use two actionButtons in shiny to control the values of a project. The code is like below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
actionButton(
inputId = "bt2",
label = "BT2",
styleclass = "info"
 ),
 actionButton(
inputId = "bt1",
label = "BT1",
styleclass = "info"
  ),

textOutput(outputId = "test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
test <- eventReactive(eventExpr = input$bt1, {
"1"
})

observeEvent(eventExpr = input$bt2, {
test <- reactive({"2"})
 })

  output$test <- renderText({
test()
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, it didn't work!
Anybody can help me？
Thank your very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I added `reactiveValues` to help you here as you want to change it using different methods such as `observeEvent`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(
    inputId = "bt2",
    label = "BT2",
    styleclass = "info"
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "bt1",
    label = "BT1",
    styleclass = "info"
  ),

  textOutput(outputId = "test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$bt1,{
    v$test <- "1"
  })

  observeEvent(input$bt2, {
    v$test  <- "2"
  })

  output$test <- renderText({
    v$test
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```